# Get the 'Filename' that is declared in the script

Tags: excel, vba

Basically every time when I get a new sheet, I would like the get the file name at the same time and place it in cell `B2`.

However, I am unable to call the file name to place it in any cell.

```
Sub GetSheets()
    Path="C:\Users\momo\Desktop\Miscellaneous Shipment Packing List\New folder\"
    Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xls")
    Do While Filename <> ""
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
        For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
            Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        Next Sheet
        Workbooks(Filename).Close
        Filename = Dir()
        Call runDel
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the rest of your code is currently working, right after:

`Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)`

You should be able to add:

`ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("B2").Value = Filename`

Like this:

```
Sub GetSheets()

Path = "C:\Users\momo\Desktop\Miscellaneous Shipment Packing List\New folder\"
Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xls")

Do While Filename <> ""
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
        For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
            Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("B2").Value = Filename
        Next Sheet
    Workbooks(Filename).Close
    Filename = Dir()
    Call runDel
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: @BigBen answer edited to point to the sheet of the highest worksheet index in `ThisWorkbook`

Comment: You're right @BigBen I assumed index worked like codenames, but it relies on the order of the sheets. I'll edit it to be Sheets(2). Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem - nice answer!

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to figure out how to reference a cell on the newly created sheet, or if it's just the filename without the path that you're trying to retrieve, then the following should work.

After setting the Filename variable using Dir(Path & "*.xls"), you can extract the filename using a combination of the [Right] and [InstrRev] functions as follows:

Range("B2") = Right(Filename, Len(Filename) - InstrRev(Filename, "\"))

To reference a cell on the newly created sheet, since you inserted the sheet after Sheet(1), the index will be 2.  It can be referenced by:
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("B2) = Filename

As in:

`Sub GetSheets()
'Update Excel Junction.com
    Path="C:\Users\momo\Desktop\Miscellaneous Shipment Packing List\New folder\"
    Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xls")
    Do While Filename <> ""
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
        For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
            Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        Next Sheet
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("B2") = Right(Filename, Len(Filename) - InStrRev(Filename, "\"))
        Workbooks(Filename).Close
        Filename = Dir()
        Call runDel
    Loop
End Sub`

0